# Where is the character being added in my wordpress search function?

Tags: wordpress, search

I have a simple search form that has started acting up after a round of changes. The issue is I can't figure out how a character is being added to a search form submission.

instead of "mysite.com/?s=candy" when I submit I'm getting "mysite.com/

No core files have been edited only theme and custom plugins. Thing is I can't pinpoint how/where the search is being handled and what would cause this issue.

Any insight would be great.

----- UPDATE -----

If I activate a different theme, such as Twenty Eleven, the search function on that theme works as expected and nothing is added to the url. That leads me to believe it's in the theme I created but why would it happen on one server and not the other?

Comment: Has anything changed the method of the search form from "GET" to "POST"?

Comment: not that I'm aware of. I'm using a custom search from that hasn't changed since I first created it. Never had issues with it before.

Comment: It might be your .htaccess file as well. See if any rules are added that remove query variables from URLs.

Comment: I removed the .htaccess file and it still adds the less than bracket to the url

Comment: Updated question with new info